# Looking for an Eclipse Plugin for Groovy

Tags: eclipse, groovy, eclipse-plugin

I need to code stuff in groovy and was hoping to use my favorite IDE to do it. Does anyone know of a plugin that allows me to create groovy projects in Eclipse? I tried googling it but a lot of them are out of date or not maintained.

Comment: Have you tried from with in eclipse (market place)?

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You can ask on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) but be sure to read [What topics can I ask about](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

I know of exactly one such plug-in, formerly maintained by the STS team, now maintained at https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse

Comment: There seem to be no version of groovy-eclipse available for Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.1a), the update site http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/2.9.2/e4.7 does not contain anything

Comment: @ola feel free to ask the maintainers on github about their plans to publish a release compatible with Oxygen.1a.

Comment: Mars and better support is only available in the snapshot update sites at the moment.  The release process is underway to produce releases for Eclipse Oxygen (and others).